# Detect which provider forces to update FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I have a state provider and a future provider that obtains data from this particular state provider. Let’s call this selectedEntityStateProvider and call future provider as weatherDataFutureProvider.

I have a PageView which user can scroll and when page changed, I update the selectedEntityStateProvider which triggers weatherDataFutureProvider to rebuild itself because it watches the selectedEntityStateProvider.

So I'm expecting at first scroll, it fetches data for new value in selectedEntityStateProvider. But when I scroll back to a previous index, it still fetches the data which already fetched before so it rebuilds itself and cause an extra network request.

Inside of onPageChanged:

```
                          ref
                              .watch(
                                  selectedEntityStateProvider
                                      .notifier)
                              .update((state) => list[value]);

                          setState(() {
                            currentIndex = value;
                          });
```

currentIndex is used to display a list of indicator widgets based on which index is selected.

weatherDataFutureProvider is like that:

```
final weatherDataFutureProvider =
    FutureProvider.family<dynamic, int>((ref, value) async {
  if (value == 1) {
    var selectedEntity = ref.watch(selectedEntityStateProvider);
    var weatherService = WeatherService();
    var weatherServiceResponse = await weatherService.callService(
      lat: selectedEntity!.address.latitude!,
      lng: selectedEntity!.address.longitude!,
    );

    return weatherServiceResponse;
  }
```

Family modifier used for to determine different type of entities. 1 is urban, 2 is rural etc and **it is coming from a parent State as a final value**.

So, at this step, how can I prevent a future provider rebuilds itself? Or is there a way that I can detect what causing this future provider rebuilds itself and losing previous data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is, you have to pass the value of `selectedEntity` as a family key somehow. Maybe you can consider using a [record](https://dart.dev/language/records) so that you can pass both `selectedEntity` and that type (the one you're currently using as family key) as the new family key, or you can use the new [code generation syntax](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation) which allows you to have multiple family keys.

Please also note that `StateProvider` is no longer recommended ***)**. If the `selectedEntity` is only used locally in a widget, consider making a regular state variable in your `StatefulWidget` instead, or use `useState` from [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks). If you really need an app-wide state management for your `selectedEntity` state, consider making a [Notifier](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/side_effects).

---

***)** As Riverpod 2.0 introduced `Notifier`/`AsyncNotifier`, `StateNotifier` is now [discouraged](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier). That means, the usage of `StateNotifierProvider` and `StateProvider` (which is a simplification of `StateNotifierProvider`) is also discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked well! Is there any document related to why we should avoid of StateProvider?

Comment: Added explanation and link in the answer!